# How to set the color and modify an Android ListView on flutter?

Tags: android, scroll, flutter, fading

I have a flutter ListView with a personalized theme set on it and the fading edge takes up the accent color of my theme. I would like to modify the parameters of the fading edge either to completly disable it or at least make it transparent (without having to modify the accent color), but I can't find anywhere where these parameters are set.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
 static const routeName = '/login-page';

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Theme(
     data: new ThemeData(
       primaryColor: primary,
       primaryColorLight: primaryLight,
       primaryColorDark: primaryDark,
       accentColor: Colors.white,
       buttonTheme: new ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent),
       brightness: Brightness.light,

      ),
  child: new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      child: new Form(
        autovalidate: true,
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: new SafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      'Log In!',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 40.0,
                          color: secondary,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    child: new Column(
                      children: [
                        new Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                                child: new EmailField(
                                  labelText: 'E-mail',
                                  validator: (val) => !isEmail(val)
                                      ? 'You must insert a valid email'
                                      : null,
                                  helperText: 'Insert your e-mail',
                                  onSaved: (String value) {
                                    _email = value;
                                  },
                                  onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _email = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              new PasswordField(
                                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                                    ? 'You must insert a password'
                                    : null,
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                helperText: 'Insert your password',
                                onSaved: (String value) {
                                  _password = value;
                                },
                                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _password = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
                                child: new LogInButton(
                                  text: '  LOGIN  ',
                                  color: primary,
                                  formKey: formKey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              //todo: add forgot password
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Now I am dealing with the problem by putting the accent color as whit cause even if I put it as transparent it will result as blackish

Comment: Can you share some of your code ?

Comment: Sure, i updated the question

Comment: Have you tried to wrap up those elements that you want to change color of, into new Theme widget and overwrite the accent color only for those ones?

Comment: Looking back at it, it's a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)