# How to remove scroll glow?

Tags: dart, flutter

By default, flutter adds a glowing effect on `ListView`/`GridView`/... to overscrolls on android phones

I would like to remove this effect entirely or on one specific scrollable.
I know that I can change `ScrollPhysics` to change between Bounce/Clamp. But this doesn't actually remove the glow effect.

What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: you can use  BouncingScrollPhysics().

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The glow effect comes from [`GlowingOverscrollIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html) added by [`ScrollBehavior`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior-class.html)

To remove this effect, you need to specify a custom `ScrollBehavior`. For that, simply wrap any given part of your application into a [`ScrollConfiguration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html) with the desired `ScrollBehavior`.

The following `ScrollBehavior` will remove the glow effect entirely :

```
class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

To remove the glow on the whole application, you can add it right under `MaterialApp` :

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehavior(),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: new MyHomePage(),
);
```

To remove it on a specific `ListView`, instead wrap only the desired `ListView` :

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyBehavior(),
  child: ListView(
    ...
  ),
)
```

---

This is also valid if you want to *change* the effect. Like adding a fade when reaching borders of the scroll view.

Comment: How can you remove the overscroll on iOS ?

Comment: @TheRedhat I just have answered your question here, you can see how to remove the overscroll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645048/how-to-remove-overscroll-on-ios

Comment: One more possible solution to avoid extending `ScrollBehavior` is to `disallowGlow()` on `OverscrollIndicatorNotification`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154780/7621577

Comment: can you please add full example or Git Code?

Comment: because i have addCustomer Form Page and i used SingleChildScrollview so where to i add this code ?

Comment: Flutter Documentation description: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior/buildViewportChrome.html

Comment: @rmalviya I honestly don't see why would you want to "avoid" this method. However, your solution also does work  but only for a `ListView`, not for a `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Remi Rousselet - I am using `ScrollablePositionedList.builder` how can I remove bouncing glow / scrolling glow? Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Remi Rousselet - I am facing this bouncing glow / scrolling glow issue because `ScrollablePositionedList.builder` does not support `controller` attribute. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Remi Remi, It worked for me. You posted first here then I found the same solution at https://flutteragency.com/remove-scrollglow-in-flutter

Comment: Low performance solution... not recommended

Comment: as buildViewportChrome is deprecated on March `21, we may have new way to implement this. check on my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68477729/2362966

Answer (score 97):

The glow will disappear by changing the ListView's `physics` property to `BouncingScrollPhysics` to imitate the List behavior on iOS.

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
}
```

Comment: any solution for ScrollablePositionedList.builder, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

The above solution did not work for me. I did this from another solution.

Wrap it with this widget to remove the shadow completely:

```dart
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
    overscroll.disallowIndicator();

    return true;
  },
  child: new ListView.builder(
    //Your stuff here. 
  ),
),
```

Comment: It's work but you must wrap to scroll widget parent if this widget inside another scroll widget.

Comment: any solution for `ScrollablePositionedList.builder`, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Sorry, noob with ScrollablePositionedList.builder. I suggest you to ask a new question to get some attention from the community.

Comment: Ok dear Bensal, Thanks, I will some more research on this topic and if I do not get any proper solution, I will post a new question. Thanks again :)

Comment: for me adding a return statement worked for pageview

NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (overscroll) {
    overscroll.disallowGlow();
return true;
  },
  child: new ListView.builder(
    //Your stuff here. 
  ),
),

Comment: Also you can change physics property of ListView widget as well to `physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),` if you like that behaviour.

Answer (score 32):

You don't need to build your own custom ScrollBehavior class. Instead, just wrap your scrollable widget in a [ScrollConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html) widget and set the behavior property to:

`const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false)`.

Full code example:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false),
  child: PageView(
    physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
    controller: model.pageController,
    children: [
      PageOne(),
      PageTwo(),
      PageThree(),
      PageFour(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: We can merge this answer with @ejabu answer, and we can use "const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false)" this line on MaterialApp's scrollBehavior parameter.

Answer (score 25):

You can try BouncingScrollPhysics with all list or grid or scrollview:

```
//ScrollView:
SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
)

//For ListView: 
ListView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
}
//GridView
GridView.Builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
)
```

Comment: any solution for ScrollablePositionedList.builder, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: thanks bro for this code

Comment: this helped! quick solution.

Answer (score 21):

You can wrap your SingleChildScrollView or ListView.

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
    overscroll.disallowGlow();
    return;
  },
  child: SingleChildScrollView()
)
```

Comment: You have to return either `true` or `false` to avoid null safety error.

Comment: `disallowGlow` is deprecated after `v2.5.0-6.0.pre` and should be replaced by `disallowIndicator`

Answer (score 21):

### Update on 2021

as buildViewportChrome is [deprecated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior/buildViewportChrome.html) on **March `21**, we may have new way to implement this

#### A. Working Solution

```dart
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {

  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      title: 'App Title',
      home: HomeUI(),
    );
  }
}
```

#### B. Explanation

By default, Flutter wraps any child widget into GlowingOverscrollIndicator as below code.

```dart
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    switch (getPlatform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return child;
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
        return GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
          axisDirection: details.direction,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          child: child, // < ----------  our Child Widget is wrapped by Glowing Indicator
        );
    }
  }
```

So we can easily override it, by directly return child without wrapping it to GlowingOverscrollIndicator

```dart
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {

  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for this great solution!

Comment: I wanted to change the color of the splash in SliverList and changing the color helped me achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can also try

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
)
```

Comment: any solution for ScrollablePositionedList.builder, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

try this work for me mybe work for you to

```dart
ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: new ScrollBehavior()..buildViewportChrome(context, null, AxisDirection.down),
          child: SingleChildScrollView()
);
```

Comment: What does this do? The `behavior` param expects a `ScrollBehavior` type, so you pass in the default `ScrollBehavior()` but call its `buildViewportChrome` method once, and ignore its return value and force "return self" with `..` syntax, how would this be different than simply pass in `behavior: ScrollBehavior()`?

Answer (score 12):

If you migrated to null safety, you might get issues with the behavior. You can use this method that works with null safety:

```dart
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
    onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification? overscroll) {
      overscroll!.disallowGlow();
      return true;
    },
  child: child,
),
```

Comment: Where exactly it's a good null safety practice? `overscroll?.disallowGlow();`

Comment: any solution for ScrollablePositionedList.builder, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @egorikem If you migrate your project to null safety, you might want to have your code non-nullable otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 10):

The currently accepted answer is outdated in the current version of Flutter.

Scroll behavior's `ScrollBehavior.copyWith()` method has an `overscroll` flag which can be set to false to avoid having to create your own ScrollBehavior class.

For example:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
    behavior: MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false),
    child : someScrollableWidget
)
```

`

It isn't good practice to just change the scroll behavior, as you may lose the native scrolling feel when running your app on different devices.

Answer (score 4):

I have used below one for Scroll body without Scroll glow effect

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: new ScrollBehavior()
                ..buildViewportChrome(context, null, AxisDirection.down),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
```

Answer (score 2):

After Flutter `2.10` update Previous NotificationListener parameter code has been removed/deprecated.
New Code

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                      onNotification: (overscroll) {
                        overscroll.disallowIndicator(); //previous code overscroll.disallowGlow();
                        return true;
                      },
                      child: ListView(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: List.generate(
                            items.length,
                            (index) => Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 13 / 9,
                                  child:
                                      LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, boxcon) {
                                    return Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                        boxShadow: const [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black12,
                                              spreadRadius: 5,
                                              blurRadius: 12)
                                        ],
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            image: NetworkImage(items[index])),
                                        color: greengradientcolor,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                                ))),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long it's been in flutter, but I think it's the easiest way if you want to disable it globally.

```
MaterialApp(
    scrollBehavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
        overscroll: false,
    ),
    ...
);
```