# How to change the color of the overscroll glow effect of ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I change the color of the glow effect of a ListView in Flutter?

[image: Glow effect]

Comment: I think you should read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/2910520, instead of removing it, you can simply change the default color in your custom `ScrollBehavior`

Comment: But this explains how to remove it. There is not a simpler way of changing its color?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Reading here for [GlowingOverscrollIndicator](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html) seems like you can change the value of `ThemeData.accentColor` to change the overscroll glow color.

You could try with something similar to this to limit the `Theme` change to the `ListView` only

```
//store the current Theme to restore it later
final ThemeData defaultTheme = Theme.of(context);

Theme(
  //Inherit the current Theme and override only the accentColor property
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    accentColor: Colors.yellow
  ),
  child: ListView.builder(
      //suppose data it's an array of strings
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          EntryItem(data[index], defaultTheme),
      itemCount: data.length,
  ),
);

//this is your class to render rows
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry, this.defaultTheme);

  final String entry;
  final ThemeData defaultTheme;

  Widget _buildTiles(String entry) {
    return Theme(
      data: defaultTheme,
      child: Text(entry)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

> You can read more about how to style your `Theme` [here](https://flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes/#themes-for-part-of-an-application)

Comment: this has been deprecated for a while now, is there any possible updates?

Answer (score 38):

Another option without using theme could be:

1- Wrap your ListView inside a `GlowingOverscrollIndicator`

2- Wrap your  `GlowingOverscrollIndicator` inside a ScrollConfiguration with a new scroll behavior

Here you have:

```
  ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
            child: GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
              axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text("testing :$index"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I think your approach is a lot cleaner than mine, thanks for sharing +1

Comment: Not Applied in SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 23):

Previous answers suggesing `ThemeData.accentColor` won't work starting with Flutter 2.2

The color of the overscroll glow effect is now defined in the `ThemeData.colorScheme.secondary` property ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html)). The easiest way to set it as below:

```dart
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      // accentColor: Color(0xff936c3b), // Previously it was implemented like this
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
        accentColor: Color(0xff936c3b), // but now it should be declared like this
      ),
    ),
```

This constructor will set the `secondary` property as below:

```
final Color secondary = accentColor ?? (isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200]! : primarySwatch);
```

Therefore, if a light theme is being used in the code, overglow effect color can also be changed by setting `ThemeData.colorScheme.primarySwatch`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Btw does anyone know why is there a hardcoded `tealAccent` for dark theme?? That's so weird...

Answer (score 5):

Simply add this to your MaterialApp widget in `main.dart`

```
theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use this code in your `MaterialApp` widget in new versions flutter. (Flutter 2)

```
theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.green),

  ),
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you use ThemeData with colorScheme, the value "secondary" affects the glow color.

ThemeData(
colorScheme: ColorScheme(
[...]
**secondary: Colors.red,**
[...]),
);

Comment: This is the right answer because `accentColor` was deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

you can also  use this inside your MaterialApp theme

```
theme: ThemeData(
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
              .copyWith(secondary: Colors.red),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres a widget to change the Overscroll-Color of the descendant widgets (in this instance your `ListView`):

```dart
/// Overrides the [GlowingOverscrollIndicator] color used by descendant widgets.
class GlowingOverscrollColorChanger extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;

  const GlowingOverscrollColorChanger({Key key, this.child, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: SpecifiableOverscrollColorScrollBehavior(color),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class SpecifiableOverscrollColorScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  final Color _overscrollColor;

  const SpecifiableOverscrollColorScrollBehavior(this._overscrollColor);

  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    switch (getPlatform(context)) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return child;
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      default:
        return GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
          child: child,
          axisDirection: axisDirection,
          color: _overscrollColor,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Usage should be:

```
Widget build() {
 GlowingOverscrollColorChanger(
  color: overscrollColor,
  child: ListView(...),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'accentColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use colorScheme.secondary instead. For more information, consult the migration guide at https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide. This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.1.pre..

Replace your code  from

```
theme: ThemeData(
      accentColor: Colors.red,
    ),
```

to this

```
    theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
      .copyWith(secondary: Colors.red),
    ),
```