# How to give screens scroll effect color in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am very confused some of my screens in the app are having the color which I want upon scrolling but some are not. I honesty don't know why or how the one's which are having the color because I don't know about it yet I'm a newbie. I know about MaterialApp and its theme I tried giving it but it didn't worked on the screens where I want the color to be orange its currently on default which is blue. I know by default flutter color is blue but I want orange.
Screenshot is attached about what I am talking about.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBhlr.jpg). Advanced thanks for the info

Comment: Could you share the code of a page where the effect is happening and a page where the effect is not happening? I believe this is only visible when the body is scrollable.

Comment: Yes the body is scrollable of course. Its scrolling effect and it comes by default with blue color. My code is too long to share here its with firebase backend I've pasted it over codeshare https://codeshare.io/5zZpbD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710761/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-overscroll-glow-effect-of-listview-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, real helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this and make sure if you are running the app in debug then hide the debug banner because with every usage of MaterialApp in every screen it will show the debug banner and the one defined in main.dart wont be of any use on it.

```
 return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    accentColor: Colors.orange,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your MaterialApp's you can define the accent color which is used as the glow color in scroll

```
theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
```