# FLUTTER: Overscroll glowing effect from ListView is not showing on android

Tags: android, flutter, listview, overscroll

I have a `ListView.separated` widget which is not showing the overscroll effect for Android. On iOS I can see the bouncing, but on Android is not showing the glowing effect, and I don't know why.

My purpose is to have the glowing effect for Android.

Here is a piece of my code structure:

```
SafeArea(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Container(
                ...
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    ...
                    ListView.separated(...)
                  
                    ],
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

I use Flutter 2.8.1 version.

Comment: This may be helpful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710761/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-overscroll-glow-effect-of-listview-in-flutter

Comment: Unfortunately is not helpful.. I tried everything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I took a look on the widget tree, I noticed that I have an widget called `NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>` where I disallowed glow effect. And it seems that, this setting was applying down to the widget tree.

My solution was to wrap my list in other `NotificationListener` widget. After doing that, the glowing effect appeared immediately.