# How to change the color of drag animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In ListView when you reach the end of the list but still try to scroll, a half bubble splashes.

How to change its color.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52710761/6750327

Answer (score 0):

Drag animation takes its color from the `accentColor` value on the `ThemeData`.