# How can I disable the animation when you scroll all the way to the top in ListView.builder

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make a list on my flutter app. But, Every time I scroll all the way to the top there is this animation showing up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7mHh.jpg, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAIyj.jpg

Is there a way to hide this animation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
    onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
      overscroll.disallowGlow();
    },
    child: ListView.builder(...));
```

As [official docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html) say

> GlowingOverscrollIndicator generates OverscrollIndicatorNotification before showing an overscroll indication. To prevent the indicator from showing the indication, call OverscrollIndicatorNotification.disallowGlow on the notification.

Comment: From [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener/onNotification.html):
Return true to cancel the notification bubbling. Return false (or null) to allow the notification to continue to be dispatched to further ancestors.

Comment: i am using SingChildScrollView and Glow Effect Show, then how to remove Glow Effect? can you please add the whole Example Or Git Code?

Comment: Did you try to put `SingChildScrollView` instead of `ListView.builder()`?

Comment: Can it be used somehow when child has `BouncingScrollPhysics()` behavior?

Comment: Haven't tried that. But if it can't - you can set another scroll physics to child, I guess

Comment: now `disallowGlow()` is deprecated. I replaced by `disallowIndicator()`

Answer (score 29):

This will help you just add this in your Listview.builder

```
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Any solution for `ScrollablePositionedList.builder`? Kindly share. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You can solve this problem using two methods.

1. if you can afford bounce back effect then simply use `ListView.builder`'s  property `physics` and set value `BouncingScrollPhysics()` like this:

   ```
   physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()
   ```
2. you can also solve it using `ScrollConfiguration` and custom `ScrollBehavior`.

[See for this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/7924072).

Comment: `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()` solution does not work with `ScrollablePositionedList.builder`. Any solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MD Khali , Here is the code using SingleChildScrollView

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overScroll) {
        overScroll.disallowGlow();
        return false;
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView( ..... )
    )
  )
 )
```

Comment: That is best solution worked for me, thanks

Comment: How can we use it with `ScrollablePositionedList.builder` kindly suggest. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, it helped me

```
const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BouncingScrollPhysics-class.html

Answer (score 0):

to disable glow effect of ClampingScrollPhysics which is the default behavior for Android you can use **scrollBehavior** property of MaterialApp

```
    return MaterialApp.router(
      scrollBehavior: _ScrollBehaviourWithoutGlowEffect(),
...............



class _ScrollBehaviourWithoutGlowEffect extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```