# Is there any way to remove the stretch effect when scrolling a list in flutter using material 3?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, material-ui, material-design, user-experience

**Left** is what the old material design had which was a glow effect.

**Right** is what the new material design has which is a stretch effect.

Inside the **Material** widget, set the theme property to this:

```
  theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Does it only for android or web too? Can you include sample snippet

Comment: I added it check the question again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020523/how-to-disable-default-widget-splash-effect-in-flutter

Answers in this question might help you.

Answer (score 3):

Disallowing indicators works for me (glow will also disappear).

```dart
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
    overscroll.disallowIndicator();
    return false;
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
   ...
  ),
),
```

Or try `ScrollConfiguration` (may require hot restart)

```dart
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: ScrollBehavior(),
  child: ListView(
    ...
  ),
),
```

refs:

- [How can I disable the animation when you scroll all the way to the top in ListView.builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154780/5445081) (SO)
- ["androidOverscrollIndicator" is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510679/androidoverscrollindicator-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used) (SO)
- [How can you change the default ScrollPhysics in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/5445081)

Comment: ScrollConfiguration did the work for me. Thanks !!