# "androidOverscrollIndicator" is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-scrollview

I am applying **stretch** effect to `Listview` , I use `androidOverscrollIndicator`

```
ScrollBehavior(
   androidOverscrollIndicator: AndroidOverscrollIndicator.stretch
),
```

I work perfectly but i see a warning at `androidOverscrollIndicator`

> 'androidOverscrollIndicator' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use
> ThemeData.useMaterial3 or override
> ScrollBehavior.buildOverscrollIndicator. This feature was deprecated
> after v2.13.0-0.0.pre.. (Documentation)   Try replacing the use of the
> deprecated member with the replacement.

How can i fix this?

This is my code:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
   behavior: const ScrollBehavior(
      androidOverscrollIndicator: AndroidOverscrollIndicator.stretch
   ),
   child: GlowingOverscrollIndicator(
       axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
       color: Colors.white,
       child: ListView(
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [ 
              //some widget
          ],
         ),
       ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking from this

```dart
child: StretchingOverscrollIndicator(
  axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 12,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text("item $index"),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: Simplest solution is to  use Material3

```
      MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
      ),
```

This is the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I dont want it to stretch nor Glow?