# How to no show the shadows generated by SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I don't want to show this shadow doing by the SingleChildScrollView... It is possible??? 
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FtWD.png)

Comment: Hello yes, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)