# How to remove overscroll on ios?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bounce, flutter-listview

By default, flutter adds a `overscroll` effect on `ListView/GridView/...` on ios

I would like to remove this effect entirely or on one specific scrollable.

What can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Comment: No, that answer doesn't explain how to remove overscroll effect on ios

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/5869913) and just added information about deleting overscroll effect.

The overscroll effect comes from `BouncingScrollPhysics` added by `ScrollBehavior`

To remove this effect, you need to specify a custom `ScrollBehavior` and override `getScrollPhysics` method. For that, simply wrap any given part of your application into a `ScrollConfiguration` with the desired `ScrollBehavior`.

The following ScrollBehavior will remove the overscroll effect entirely :

```
class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) => ClampingScrollPhysics();
}
```

You can also remove glow effect with override of method buildViewportChrome like this:

```
@override
Widget buildViewportChrome(BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) => child;
```

To remove the overscroll on the whole application, you can add it right under MaterialApp :

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyBehavior(),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

To remove it on a specific ListView, instead wrap only the desired ListView :

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyBehavior(),
  child: ListView(
    ...
  ),
)
```

or just set physics: `ClampingScrollPhysics()` in the ListView

Comment: Couldn't you just set physics: ClampingScrollPhysics() in the ListView?

Comment: can you please add full example or Git Code?

Answer (score 36):

You don't need to do those fancy stuff if you only want to remove overscroll behavior on iOS. Simply, use:

```
ListView(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
)
```