# How to remove blue/grey scroll animation of tabbarview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, tabbar

I have a TabBarview when slide from one page to another splash appear in the very side of the page.
 I don't want the splash highlight to appear on both sides.

Although tabbarview has physics and when set to  bouncingscrollphysics() this shape shouldnt appear, like what occur in list view, but nothing changed.

Tried another solution:  I wrapped the tabbarview with a theme and changed the highlight color and splash color to colors.transparent but that didn't work either. Here is the code for my TabBarview.
and here is the ui, and how it looks.

[image]

```
 Theme(
                  data: new ThemeData(
                      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                      highlightColor: Colors.transparent),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: model.types.map((String type) {
                      List<Subscription> subssOfThisType =
                          model.historySubscription.where((Subscription sub) {
                        return sub.package.name == type;
                      }).toList();

                      final cards = subssOfThisType.map(
                        (s) {
                          return HistoryCard(
                            sub: s,
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList();

                      return ListView(
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 8),
                        children: cards ?? Container(),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to make some breaking changes in the original code of TabBar hten use the below package

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tab_bar_no_ripple

=== For your use case ===

To keep things simple ... change physics to BouncingScrollPhysics()

If you don't want that bouncy effect then check the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/10104608

Comment: this is what I did , you can find the edit above. However , it doesnot work

Comment: which attribute will be set in material widget ?

Comment: unfortunately it wouldn't work with me as I need the on tap function in the original Tab Bar

Comment: Try using the controller it provides...if it suits your need.

Comment: you mean a controller in the tab bar view ?

Comment: Yes...Please describe your issue if possible so that I can provide an appropriate solution

Comment: Wait a sec...Are you referring to the blue scrollanimation?

Comment: yess this what I am referring to the blue scroll animation "this splash"

Comment: See from what that overscroll glow appears and change its physics to  BouncingScrollPhysics()

Comment: yes yes I have used physics to BouncingScrollPhysics() but it didnt work . However the link you added helped in removing this blue scroll animation thank you lots

Comment: Glad it helped you...I doubt that overscroll glow is coming from somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

change physics to BouncingScrollPhysics()

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to try ScrollConfiguration?

it works fine.

```dart
body: ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyBehavior(),
  child: const TabBarView(
    children: [
      TabPage(icon: Icons.directions_car),
      TabPage(icon: Icons.directions_bike),
    ],
  ),
),
```

```
class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119796/9819094