# How to remove the animation that comes when finished scrolling a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, and I want to remove the animation that comes when I finished scrolling a ListView in a Flutter App. Here is my code snippet.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("My First App"),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Question(questions[tempIndex]["questionText"]),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: 
            ListView.builder(

              itemCount: questions[tempIndex]["answers"].length,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return Answer(this.answerQuestion,questions[tempIndex]["answers"][position]);
              },

            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide your code

Comment: @FatimaHossny added the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Comment: but how do I integrate it to the ListView? that's the problem I am stuck with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Rémi Rousselet answer in this link 
[How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow) .
you need to add this `MyBehavior` class in any dart file or in the same file and wrap list view with ScrollConfiguration like this code .

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My First App"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Question(questions[tempIndex]["questionText"]),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ScrollConfiguration(
                  behavior: MyBehavior(),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: questions[tempIndex]["answers"].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                      return Answer(this.answerQuestion,
                          questions[tempIndex]["answers"][position]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```