# How can I remove/disable vertical PageView top/bottom color - scroll glow - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know if there is a way to remove the PageView color that occurs when the user reaches the end of the items?
this is an image that describes what I mean
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHP1u.png)

```dart
PageView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    controller: _controller,
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      _isValid = false;
                      return [
                          SizedBox.expand(...),
                          SizedBox.expand(...),
                          SizedBox.expand(...),
                          SizedBox.expand(...),
                        ][index];
                    },
                  )
```

I found the complete and right answer here: [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is provided by [ScrollBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior-class.html). You need to provide your custom [ScrollBehavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior-class.html) and wrap it inside a [ScrollConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html).

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
 @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
     BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
     return child;
  }
}
```

To remove the effect in your PageView

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: CustomScrollBehavior(),
  child: PageView.builder(
    ...
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

above one is not worked for me , after the new flutter v2 ( sdk 2.8.1),

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (overscroll) {
   overscroll.disallowIndicator();
    return true;
   },
child: SingleChildScrollView(

 )
)
```