# NestedScrollView persistent header sometimes looks awkward

Tags: flutter, nestedscrollview

Often when scroll is fast enough my app shows a small transparent line between scrolling view and persistent header.

Minimal reproducible code:
https://gist.github.com/Moonspeaker/0e8573ff6620a7e00b8f7b04937b51a1

This is how it looks recorded on video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDxu1NTkaMA&feature=youtu.be

I have no clue how to fix this. The issue seems to be in `Align` widget with `Alginment.bottomCenter`. `Column` with `MainAxisAlignment.end` works the same way.

[image: Flutter nested scroll view persistent header bug]

Comment: Can you circle out the "small transparent line" you're referring to? I can only see a "big white line" and a "small red line below the white line".

Comment: The background of the whole app is red. That small red line is a margin between listview and header that should not be there.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue using the "minimal reproducable code". I'm just using emulator though (Android & iOS).

Comment: it happens in both release and debug versions on emulator and real device. Scroll up and down fast several times and you'll be seeing this happen

Comment: The screenshot was taken in the app compiled from this gist. Tested on sdk: ">=2.12.0-29.10.beta <3.0.0", latest beta channel flutter.

Comment: It is easier to reproduce if you let scrollphysics finish the scroll releasing gesture halfway

Comment: Maybe it only happens in beta channel. I'm using stable channel, and can't replicate the issue.

Comment: This is how it looks to me on latest stable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDxu1NTkaMA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Same on emulator

Comment: I noticed that setting heap to 1gb and ram to 8gb+ makes it harder to reproduce it on emulator somehow

Comment: Do you meant about this transparent section https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow#:~:text=To%20remove%20this%20effect%2C%20you,ScrollConfiguration%20with%20the%20desired%20ScrollBehavior%20.&text=This%20is%20also%20valid%20if,borders%20of%20the%20scroll%20view.
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your `SliverPersistentHeader` with a [SliverOverlapAbsorber](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverOverlapAbsorber-class.html)
usually when working with NestedScrollView you will need to wrap the header in this object in order to not encounter rare scrolling artifacts like the red line you described.

I was not able to reproduce the issue with the change stated below.
But you could also take a look to [SliverOverlapInjector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverOverlapInjector-class.html) and the [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) class documentation which has examples using both of these widgets

```
...
NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, scrolling) => [
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle:
                    NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: _Delegate(),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
...
```