# use fulutter_inappwebview how remove bounce scroll glow

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-inappwebview, glow

I tried using the code explained online, other listview can be removed, but using Flutter_ Inappwebview plugin, this effect cannot be removed after opening the webpage

Other answer which I followed: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

[image]

What can I do? I can only remove this rolling rebound effect

Comment: Please share your code attempt so far so we can work on top of it to provide you best possible answer, thanks

Comment: The example I used https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/multi_webview_tab_manager/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the widget OverscrollIndicatorNotification

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
  onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
    overscroll.disallowIndicator();

    return true;
  },
  child: <Widget Here>,
),
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it didn't work