# When i swipe down in my flutter app a blue semi-circle appears from the top of the app. What is this? and how do i get rid of it?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a mobile application/game in flutter that presents the user with a grid of letters they can swipe left/right/up/down etc. During testing on a virtual phone (Android studio) when i swipe up/down i am not able to swipe the cells up/down as a semi-circle appears at the top (if I'm swiping down) and bottom (if I'm swiping up) of the grid widget.[[Image of what i get when swiping down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyilc.png)][[Image of what i get when swiping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1OFQ.png)].

Here is the code for the grid widget.

```
Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount:
                      gridSize, // Set the number of columns in the grid
                ),
                itemCount:
                    gridSize * gridSize, // Total number of cells in the grid
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // Calculate the row and column of the current cell based on the index
                  int rowIndex = index ~/ gridSize;
                  int colIndex = index % gridSize;
                  String cellValue = letterGrid[rowIndex]
                      [colIndex]; // Get the letter value for the current cell
                  bool isSelected = _selectedCells.contains(Offset(
                      rowIndex.toDouble(),
                      colIndex.toDouble())); // Check if the cell is selected
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () =>
                        _handleCellTap(rowIndex, colIndex), // Handle cell tap
                    onPanStart: (details) {
                      initalPanOffset = details
                          .localPosition; // Record the starting offset of a swipe gesture
                    },
                    onPanUpdate: (details) {
                      if (isSwipeInProgress) return;
                      // Calculate the difference between the starting offset and current offset
                      Offset offsetDiff =
                          details.localPosition - initalPanOffset;
                      double horizontalDelta = offsetDiff.dx.abs();
                      double verticalDelta = offsetDiff.dy.abs();
                      // Check if the user swipes horizontally or vertically and initiate the corresponding swipe method
                      if (horizontalDelta > swipeThreshold &&
                          horizontalDelta > verticalDelta) {
                        if (offsetDiff.dx > 0) {
                          swipeRowRight(rowIndex); // Swipe the row to the right
                          _swipeDirection = SwipeDirection.right;
                        } else {
                          swipeRowLeft(rowIndex); // Swipe the row to the left
                          _swipeDirection = SwipeDirection.left;
                        }
                        isSwipeInProgress = true;
                      } else if (verticalDelta > swipeThreshold &&
                          verticalDelta > horizontalDelta) {
                        if (offsetDiff.dy > 0) {
                          swipeColumnDown(colIndex); // Swipe the column down
                          _swipeDirection = SwipeDirection.down;
                        } else {
                          swipeColumnUp(colIndex); // Swipe the column up
                          _swipeDirection = SwipeDirection.up;
                        }
                        isSwipeInProgress = true;
                      }
                    },
                    onPanEnd: (details) {
                      isSwipeInProgress =
                          false; // Reset the swipe progress status
                    },
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: isFlashingGreen
                            ? confirmedWordBackgroundColor
                            : isFlashingRed
                                ? errorBackgroundColor
                                : isSelected
                                    ? selectedBackgroundColor
                                    : colorGrid[rowIndex][
                                        colIndex], // Set the cell color based on selection
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            0), // Rounded corners for the cell
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          cellValue, // Display the letter value in the center of the cell
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24,
                            color: isSelected
                                ? selectedTextColor
                                : unselectedTextColor,
                          ), // Styling for the letter text
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I haven't really tried anything because i don't know where to start... I'm only new to flutter development so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `physics` property of `GridView` to disable the effect.

```
GridView.builder(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // or NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
  ...
```

Also, you may find other solutions here:

[How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you for that! I had no idea what the effect was called :)