# Disable animation of CustomScrollView after clicking button return to top

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a Flutter application with a CustomScrollView.
My application can scroll and if i scroll far enought i get a button to return at the top of the page.
When i press the button i go back at the top and the CustoScrollView does a dropdown animation.

```
CustomScrollView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  primary: false,
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
```

I don't want the animation to be excecuted but i can't find a way to do so

I tried to add this but it's not working

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
    onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
      overscroll.disallowIndicator();
    },
    child: CustomScrollView(...)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow)

Comment: Sadly nothing works, i'v tried all of them before askying my question :(

Comment: Please add some images or a video to show your problem, to be honest, it is hard to understand what is the exact issue.